# Filter that returns multiple values, vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to use a filter to display products. Basically the user clicks on the checkbox and it returns the title(s).

I am trying to get data from an array called 'products'. Which has titles in it.

What I can't do is if the user clicks on two checkboxes or three, it doesn't display the output. It goes blank instead.

E.g I want to select both Car and House. At the moment I can select Car or House. If I select both, it just disappears.

Will really appreciate your help.

Thanks. 
***Edited***
I am trying to chain this under `filteredSearch()` 
The products array contains more than just Car, House. 
P.topic is in the products[] array.

```
data: {
   products:[],

.....
computed: {
    filteredProducts() {
      return this.products.filter(x => x.name === this.loggedUser[0].text);
    },
    filteredSearch() {

        return this.products
                   .filter(p => p.topic.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()))
                   .filter(p => p.price <= this.priceFilter)


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 2nd call to `filter` is acting on an already filtered array.

Only items that match "House" will now be passing through your 2nd match for "Car", and since none apparently does, you get an empty result.

Given this is Vue, I would have a `filters` array, where I would store all the filters selected. Then in a `computed` prop, I would run through all topics and return the ones that match ANY of the filters in the filters array.

As a quick example, and there's other things that you'd need to figure out.

```
// parts of a Vue component

data: () => ({
  topics: ["Houses", "Boats", "Cars", "Bicycles", "Skates"],
  filters: ["Houses", "Cars"]
}),

computed: {
  filteredTopics() {
    return this.filters.length && this.topics.filter(topic => this.filters.includes(topic)) || this.topics
  },
  // or using match
  matchedTopics() {
    return this.filters.length && this.topics.filter(topic => this.filters.some(filter => topic.match(filter))) || this.topics
  },
  sortedAndMatchedTopics() {
    // basically pick on the already filtered result and sort it someway, for example
    return this.matchedTopics.sort( /* ... your logic for sorting here */ )
  }
}
```

Obviously this data is different from yours, so it would have to be adjusted, also, you'd have to add/remove items from `filters` when they are selected/deselected.

Made a small fiddle to better explain how this might be achieved in Vue https://jsfiddle.net/Compay/w63yj9Lx/10/

Comment: You need to include the case when no topic is selected (which means match any topic).

Comment: I'm new to vue & js. I have an array called products, which is where i get the data from. Do I just use event trigger on checkbox, v-model for true/false. then create a function under methods which does something like. 'if checkbox = true, then push this to the array?' Sorry I might not be getting this right.

Comment: @Calv your question is specific to filtering so without more code examples we can't help you in addition if it deviates from the current question.

Comment: @Calv I made a small JSFiddle that might help you get on the correct path on how to achieve what you're looking for in Vue, let me know if it helps https://jsfiddle.net/Compay/w63yj9Lx/

Comment: That is exactly what I want. Thank you so much. It will take me some time to understand your code but I really appreciate that you took your time to make me a jsfiddle. I might be asking for too much, but I also want to sort stuff in ascending or descending order(still using the p.topic). Is this something doable under 'filters?'

Comment: For sorting, I would compound computed props, meaning, I would create a new computed prop that picks after the `matchedProducts` computed prop and sorts it. Check the updated answer above for an idea

Comment: One thing to remember, if sorting never changes, maybe it needs to happen *before* the filtering, so you'd use the sorted computed prop inside the computed prop that filters. The way Vue works is, it will update computed props when their dependencies change, in the answer above, sorting would always happen when the filters change since `matchedTopics` would have changed as well.

Comment: I've run in to a problem with the code on js fiddle. It works fine as long as there are 3 products in the array. If there are 4 or more, in my case 25. it starts duplicating them. console spits out the following error ' Duplicate keys detected: ' '. This may cause an update error.' i.e i have home repeated about 10 times, car repeated about 6 etc.

Comment: I think I understand, you're getting repeated filters, is that it? I've updated the fiddle so the `possibleFilters` returns unique values https://jsfiddle.net/Compay/w63yj9Lx/10/

Comment: Yup thats it. Thanks. What can I do to make it work with search? i.e if I search for xyz and select 'house' it should show nothing. Instead it prioritises house and shows house.

Comment: Add a v-model to an input and use the value of that in a new computed prop that uses the filtered by topic computed prop, and filters again using the value of the v-model. Check here how to do input bindings, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html, also, it shows an easier way to check/uncheck the filters (checkboxes)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202837/discussion-between-calv-and-leite).

Answer (score 1):

When you apply `filter` to an array you're essentially reducing that array to match the expression supplied. That applies to any subsequent `filter` applied. So really there's no logic in doing it this way with multiple expressions.

Instead, you can collect the values outside the filter and use one `filter` method that checks if the topic of each element in the array matches any of the filtered values you collected earlier.

```
const filterByTopic = []
this.checkBox2 && filterByTopic.push('House')
this.checkBox3 && filterByTopic.push('Car')

const filtered = myArray.filter(p => !filterByTopic.length || filterByTopic.some(val => p.topic.match(val)))
```

Comment: This will return nothing when no topic is selected. It's a special case: when no topic is selected, return everything.

Comment: @DecadeMoon duly noted.